# The type initializer for 'BBDXamarinForms.Droid.Library.Config.BBDXamarinConfig' threw an exception

Tags: xamarin.forms, blackberry, microsoft-dynamics, blackberry-dynamics

I am creating a Xamarin forms app using blackberry dynamics SDK in it. While I am initializing blackberry dynamics, I get an error in function

```
BBDXamarinConfig.Initialize();
```

I added the SDK (dll files) of blackberry dynamics in Xamarin form app for Android and iOS.

```
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, 
        savedInstanceState);
        BBDXamarinConfig.Initialize();
        LoadApplication(new App());
        }
```

The error message (obtained while initializing blackberry dynamics for Xamarin in xamarin.android) reads:

> The type initializer for 'BBDXamarinForms.Droid.Library.Config.BBDXamarinConfig' threw an exception

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with the exact error(s) produced.

Comment: i am getting" The type initializer for 'BBDXamarinForms.Droid.Library.Config.BBDXamarinConfig' threw an exception"
 error while initializing blackberry dynamics for xamarin in xamarin.android.